# CALayer Array with Multiple of Same Object

Tags: iphone, arrays, core-animation, nsmutablearray, calayer

Am I trying to create a game where an obstacle is constantly fired at the user.  I have an NSMutableArray so I can access all the obstacles as a group.  Here is my code:

```
CALayer *obstacle = [[[CALayer alloc] init] autorelease];
UIImage *obstacleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle.png"];
obstacle.contents =  (id)obstacleImage.CGImage;
obstacle.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, starImage.size.width/2, starImage.size.width/2);
int xPosition = (arc4random()%(360-0))+0;
obstacle.position = CGPointMake(xPosition, 20);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:obstacle];
[self.obstacleArray addObject:obstacle];
```

My questions is: How would I access the objects in this array? I want to be able to access the latest object so I can animate it.  I have looked through the [NSMutableArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) , but still can't find anything. I have tried this:

```
NSLog(@"%d",[obstacleArray indexOfObject:obstacle]);
```

But  all it returns is: 0.  Is there an easy solution to this problem that I'm just not seeing?  Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[obstacleArray lastObject]` or `[obstacleArray objectAtIndex:[obstacleArray count]-1]` to get the last Object. You can find that in the NSArray Class Reference. (Since it's the parent class of NSMutableArray)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but all that is outputted is (null).  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Would you mind to paste your code where you generate your obstacleArray MutableArray?

Comment: @AndyB Your obstacle array is probably null. `self.obstacleArray = [NSMutableArray array]`